# Reproducir automáticamente un audio cuando un target aparece

Tags: android, unity3d, vuforia

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de realidad aumentada usando **Unity** y **Vuforia**, tengo el siguiente código en c#.

```
public AudioSource soundTarget;
public AudioClip clipTarget; 
private AudioSource[] allAudioSources;

//function to stop all sounds
void StopAllAudio()
{
    allAudioSources = FindObjectsOfType(typeof(AudioSource)) as AudioSource[];
    foreach (AudioSource audioS in allAudioSources)
    {
        audioS.Stop();
    }
}

//function to play sound
void playSound(string ss)
{
    clipTarget = (AudioClip)Resources.Load(ss);
    soundTarget.clip = clipTarget;
    soundTarget.loop = false;
    soundTarget.playOnAwake = false;
    soundTarget.Play();
}
```

El problema es al probar en un teléfono con Android la apk que genero con Unity no se reproducen los sonidos, sin embargo al probar la aplicación directamente desde Unity (En este caso se usa la computadora) los audios sí se reproducen.
No sé si por el hecho de que sea Android el código en C# tenga que ser diferente.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ImageTargetPlayAudio : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler {
    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

void Start () {
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour> ();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour) {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler (this);
    }
}
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus, TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED || newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED) 
    {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.Play ();
    } else {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource> ();
        audio.Stop ();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Hola bienvenido a [es.so]. Es posible que tu respuesta se apropiada, pero al contener sólo código, no podemos aprender de ella. ¿Porqué la misma es la solución? Comenta como lo soluciona y la respuesta podrá ser mucho más eficaz y no considerada como de baja calidad. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].